# Qt - Remove shortcut -- Ambiguous shortcut overload

Tags: c++, qt, qmdiarea

**Extraneous Information:**
I am attempting to build an application using Qt. This application features a QMdiArea and a child-window. My child-window will have a menu which can be integrated into the QMdiArea or segregated and attached to the child itself. Though, this is a bit more detail than needed...

**Problem:**
I would like my child-widget to have a menu with a shortcut, "CTRL+W." But, because I am using a QMdiArea, the shortcut is already used causing:

> QAction::eventFilter: Ambiguous shortcut overload: Ctrl+W

How can I get rid of this shortcut and claim it within my child widget instead?

**Update:**
Here is what I've tried with no luck:

```
class MDI : public QMdiArea
{
    Q_OBJECT
    private:
    bool event(QEvent *tEvent)
    {
        if (tEvent->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        {
            QKeyEvent* ke = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(tEvent);
            if (ke->key()== Qt::Key_W && ke->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier)
            emit KeyCW();
            return true;
        }
        return QMdiArea::event(tEvent);
    }
public:
signals:
    void KeyCW();
};
```

This works if I do something as simple as change `Qt::Key_W` to  `Qt::Key_L.` The key-combo is received and event is thrown. With W, it just never happens. I've also tried moving `event` to QMainWindow as well as an eventFilter in the subwindow to QMdiArea. It seems that it is a little overly complicated to do something as simple as remove default key-handlers from within QMdiArea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, what I am looking for is not possible short of writing my own MDIArea.

> [The shortcut is set in QMdiSubWindowPrivate::createSystemMenu() during
>   the construction of a QMdiSubWindow, I doubt that you can remove it
>   without having to patch Qt libs.](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/11921)

Hopefully at some point someone will disprove this or QT will make changes. Meanwhile, it looks like we will all need to stay away from these pre-assigned shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable this shortcut like this:

```
for( QAction *action : subWindow->systemMenu()->actions() ) {
    if( action->shortcut() == QKeySequence( QKeySequence::Close ) ) {
        action->setShortcut( QKeySequence() );
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get rid of the pre-defined close action of the `QMdiSubWindow` altogether by using `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` as additional flag when adding the subwindow.

```
QMdiSubWindow *subWindow2 = mdiArea.addSubWindow(internalWidget2, 
                                                 Qt::Widget | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | 
                                                 Qt::WindowMinMaxButtonsHint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass QMdiArea and reimplement `keyPressEvent()`.  That should work.

```
  void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event){

    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_W and event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier){
      // handle it
    }else{
      return QMdiArea::keyPressEvent(event);
    }
  }
```

You could also use event filters.  I don't enough about your class hierarchy, but I hope you get the idea.

```
bool CustomMdiArea::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event){
     if(object == yourChildWindow && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
         QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
         if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_W and keyEvent->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier) {
             //handle it
             return true;
         }else{
             return false;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: So is there no way to disable the shortcut that QMdiArea created? Basically meaning that if I want use of the short-cut key I have to use signal/slot connections between the two?

Comment: Also, if that is absolutely the only way, is there any harm in leaving the ambiguous shortcut? IE: Installing the shortcut onto the widgets menu? I really don't want to sacrifice the "Ctrl+W" shortcut reminder in the menu-bar, since that is the best way to tell a user a shortcuts function.

Comment: To alter `QMdiArea`'s default behaviour in regards to a specific key event is to subclass it and reimplement `keyPressEvent()`.  Another way is to use event filters.

Comment: This problem seems to get deeper and deeper, I am completely confused. I thought about what you wrote, and in order to get that working, I would have to subclass QMdiArea and emit a signal to QMainWindow which would handle it from there. Well, I decided to try it, and... no luck. I can capture other keys, but still, even through the event member of QMdiArea, I never receive the key-combo CTRL+W. I am updating my post to show some code...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by setting the shortcut context for my close action.  By setting it to `Qt::WidgetShortcut`, I no longer get the ambiguous shortcut overload.  Here is how I'm setting up my close action now:

```
  closeAction = new QAction(tr("&Close"), this);
  closeAction->setShortcut(Qt::CTRL|Qt::Key_W);
  closeAction->setShortcutContext(Qt::WidgetShortcut);
  connect(closeAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), mdiArea, SLOT(closeActiveSubWindow()));
```